# How to clean the ---> '' character from my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with some columns of my interest, for example, discounted_price, actual_price, discount_percentage, rating and rating_count. At this columns i have some data that i want to convert to float, for that reason i try first to clean them using the following code:

```
eliminar = ['₹',',','|','%',' ']
columnas = ['discounted_price','actual_price','discount_percentage','rating','rating_count']

for i in columnas:
    for j in eliminar:
        az[i] = az[i].str.replace(j,'')
        az[i] = az[i].str.rstrip()
```

at that point everything is ok, but then, when i try this code:

```
az['discounted_price'] = az['discounted_price'].astype('float')
az['actual_price'] = az['actual_price'].astype('float')
az['discount_percentage'] = az['discount_percentage'].astype('float')
az['rating'] = az['rating'].astype('float')
az['rating_count'] = az['rating_count'].astype('float')
```

the following message:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17308\2874206531.py in <module>
      2 az['actual_price'] = az['actual_price'].astype('float')
      3 az['discount_percentage'] = az['discount_percentage'].astype('float')
----> 4 az['rating'] = az['rating'].astype('float')
      5 az['rating_count'] = az['rating_count'].astype('float')

c:\Users\gerar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5910         else:
   5911             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5912             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5913             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5914 

c:\Users\gerar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    417 
    418     def astype(self: T, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise") -> T:
--> 419         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    420 
    421     def convert(

c:\Users\gerar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    302                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    303                 else:
...
-> 1181         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1182 
   1183     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

i don't know how to eliminate the '' characther to continue.

I already try the rstrip method

Comment: It's not a character: it's an empty string. A string not containing anything; of length zero. It certainly won't contain a floating point number, so you can't convert it.

Comment: It means that after scrubbing, you had a empty string as a value in the 'rating' column. So, wht do you want to happen in that case? You may want `astype('float', errors='ignore')` to add NaN.

Comment: As an aside, you can use a regex replace instead of nested fors to tighten up your code. `az.replace(r"[₹,|% ]", "", regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bug. If rating is never supposed to have an empty string, then this error says you have bad data and that's the thing that needs to be fixed. That's why I asked what your error handling should be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i eliminate de '' characther in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563472/how-can-i-eliminate-de-characther-in-python)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you already made some hours ago and got closed. Edit the original question so it can be reopened. **Do not repost the same question.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `pandas.to_numeric` instead, with the option `errors=coerce`. If I remember correctly, then you'll get NaNs for the empty strings, and floating point numbers otherwise:

```
az['rating'] = pd.to_numeric(az['rating'], errors='coerce')
```

You could then replace or remove the NaNs with `pd.DataFrame.fillna` or `pd.Dataframe.dropna`, or the Series equivalent methods.

Comment: Thak you so much, that works

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead of your line:

```
az['rating'] = az['rating'].replace("", None).astype(float)
```

which will give NaN values for elements which as empty strings